# Removing text in all kinds of braces

Tags: c#, string

I have a string "hello [world] this {is} a (test)" I want to remove all text in braces, e.g. returning "hello  this  a". But only if the braces match.
Anyone have a nice neat solution?

Comment: What is the desired behaviour if braces don't match? 
"this {is another {test}"
How about nesting?
"this is {another {test}}"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s*?(?:\(.*?\)|\[.*?\]|\{.*?\})", String.Empty);
```

The `\s*?` matches any white space before the brackets.
The `(?: )` is a non-matching parenthesis to group the conditions inside it.
The `\(.*?\)` is mathing parentheses with zero or more characters between them.